# Pyspark Dataframe TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a new coulmn to an existing dataframe in Pyspark by searching one of the filed 'script' and returning match as the entry for new column.

```
  import re as re
   def sw_fix(data_str):
        if re.compile(r'gaussian').search(data_str):
           cleaned_str = 'gaussian'
        elif re.compile(r'gromacs').search(data_str):
           cleaned_str = 'gromacs'
        else:
           cleaned_str = 'ns'
        return cleaned_str
   sw_fix_udf = udf(sw_fix, StringType())
   k=df.withColumn("software_new", sw_fix_udf(df.script))
```

The code runs fine and generates  dataframe k with the new column with correct match, however I am unable to do any operation on the the newly added column

```
k.filter(k.software_new=='gaussian').show()
```

throws an error,  TypeError: expected string or buffer.

I chekced the datatype of the newly added column

```
f.dataType for f in k.schema.fields
```

which shows StringType.

However this one works, where sw_app is a existing column in the original dataframe.

```
k.filter(k.sw_app=='gaussian').select('sw_app','software_new').show(5)

   +--------+------------+                                                         
   |  sw_app|software_new|
   +--------+------------+
   |gaussian|    gaussian|
   |gaussian|    gaussian|
   |gaussian|    gaussian|
   |gaussian|    gaussian|
   |gaussian|    gaussian|
   +--------+------------+
```

Any hints on why I can't process software_new field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine for me without any issues. see below demo in pyspark repl.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
>>> import re as re
>>> def sw_fix(data_str):
...     if re.compile(r'gaussian').search(data_str):
...        cleaned_str = 'gaussian'
...     elif re.compile(r'gromacs').search(data_str):
...        cleaned_str = 'gromacs'
...     else:
...        cleaned_str = 'ns'
...     return cleaned_str
...
>>>
>>> sw_fix_udf = udf(sw_fix, StringType())
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(['gaussian text', 'gromacs text', 'someother text'], StringType())
>>>
>>> k=df.withColumn("software_new", sw_fix_udf(df.value))
>>> k.show()
+--------------+------------+
|         value|software_new|
+--------------+------------+
| gaussian text|    gaussian|
|  gromacs text|     gromacs|
|someother text|          ns|
+--------------+------------+

>>> k.filter(k.software_new == 'ns').show()
+--------------+------------+
|         value|software_new|
+--------------+------------+
|someother text|          ns|
+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: I tried your example data and it worked fine. So I assume the problem is with my dataframe df. The script field is StringType and  software_new field is also StringType. I do not understand how it possible to have a non stringType in the software_new filed.

Comment: yeah.. something should have been messed up in your setup..  BTW can you accept this answer :)